# Differential equation containing integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I have trouble uderstanding a part of the solution of the ode below.

$y'(t)+y(t)=\int _{0} ^{2} y(t)dt$  **(1)**

The solution is this:

Let $u=\int _{0} ^{2} y(t)dt$

$(1) \Rightarrow y'(t)+y(t)=u$ **(2)**

The ode has intagrating factor of $μ(t)=e^t$

$\xrightarrow{(2)*μ(t)} e^ty'+e^ty=e^tu \Leftrightarrow(e^ty(t))'=e^tu $

$\Leftrightarrow e^ty(t)=\int e^tu dt$

Here's what I don't get, the answer goes on like this

$e^ty(t)=e^tu+c$

It seems to me that this would be the case if $u$ was not dependat to $t$ but since $u=\int _{0} ^{2} y(t)dt$ it's obviously dependant..

What am I missing here? Can someone explain this part of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=\int _{0} ^{2} y(t)dt$ is a number, not a function of $t$.

Comment: Ohhh that's seems pretty obvious now.. Since it's a definite integral..